# Online Poker League

Tags: tournament

I have played in a live poker league, which hosts a game each week, and players accumulate points based on their positions in the tournament.  The top 10 at the end of the month from each venue progress to finals etc.

I am wondering if anyone knows if such leagues exist online, where there are regular tournaments and points given based on placings (and hopefully finals and prizes at the end).

Comment: I wish I knew some. I would even play for fun. I tried to start one on BluffAve but I can't get people I know to commit.

Comment: Let's start our own online league! Not sure how/if we could play for $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were running some sort of online team league on [PKR](http://www.PKR.com) every tuesday, but I am not sure if thats still active.

I think there is also an official one running there.

You could also check out this page:

[Online Poker World Championship](http://onlinepokerworldchampionship.com/)

Comment: PKR have been shut down, I know pokerstars has an online poker school league tiered at different levels.

Comment: PS used to let you create such a league *but* according to local laws regarding online poker, it might not be in each and every country. But I was part of a small local league (15+ players) : choose the name, the schedule, prize pool and BI, and done...